# Channels in Golang with TCP/IP socket not working

Tags: go, tcp, unix-socket

I just started writting a Golang client for a server that I've made in C with TCP/IP sockets, then I figured out that my channel wasn't working.

Any ideas why ?

```
func reader(r io.Reader, channel chan<- []byte) {
  buf := make([]byte, 2048)
  for {
    n, err := r.Read(buf[:])
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    channel <- buf[0:n]
  }
}
func client(e *gowd.Element) {
 f, err := os.Create("/tmp/dat2")
 if err != nil {
    log.Fatal()
 }
 read := make(chan []byte)
 c, err := net.Dial("tcp", "127.0.0.1:4242")
 if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
 }
 go reader(c, read)
 for {
    buf := <-read
    n := strings.Index(string(buf), "\n")
    if n == -1 {
        continue
 }
 msg := string(buf[0:n])
 if msg == "WELCOME" {
    fmt.Fprint(c, "GRAPHIC\n")
 }
 f.WriteString(msg + "\n")
}
```

Testing my server with netcat results in the following output : 
http://pasted.co/a37b2954

But i only have : http://pasted.co/f13d56b4

I'm new to chan in Golang so maybe I'm wrong (I probably am)

Comment: Can you define "not working" within the question itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Channel usage looks alright, however retrieving value from channel would overwrite previously read value at `buf := <-read` since your waiting for newline.

Also you can use `bufio.Reader` to read string upto newline.

Your code snippet is partial so its not feasible to execute, try and let me know:

```
func reader(r io.Reader, channel chan<- string) {
    bufReader := bufio.NewReader(conn)
    for {
        msg, err := bufReader.ReadString('\n')
        if err != nil { // connection error or connection reset error, etc
           break
        }
        channel <- msg
    }
}

func client(e *gowd.Element) {
    f, err := os.Create("/tmp/dat2")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal()
    }
    read := make(chan string)
    c, err := net.Dial("tcp", "127.0.0.1:4242")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    go reader(c, read)
    for {
        msg := <-read
        if msg == "WELCOME" {
            fmt.Fprint(c, "GRAPHIC\n")
        }
        f.WriteString(msg + "\n")
    }
    //...
}
```

---

**EDIT:**

Please find example of generic TCP client to read data. Also I have removed scanner from above code snippet and added buffer reader.

```
func main() {
    conn, err := net.Dial("tcp", "127.0.0.1:4242")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    reader := bufio.NewReader(conn)
    for {
        msg, err := reader.ReadString('\n')
        if err != nil {
            break
        }
        fmt.Println(msg)
    }
}
```

Comment: if expect string, it prefer `chan string`.

Comment: Thank you, the whole code is garbage with html and whatever, unreadable.
I use your code, but it produces nothing, i have no more message in my file...

Comment: @BorisLeMéec I'm sorry, what are you trying to say?

Comment: Sorry, my english is a total disaster tonight.
I haven't published the entire code because it would be unreadable.
Anyway i tried your code but now I can't even receive one message from the server, at the end of the execution, the file in tmp is still empty

Comment: I do not have knowledge on your code.  However I will create generic TCP socket read and will update the answer. Then you can customize it for your need.